# Showing different text marker or color marker over OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, marker

I want to show different places over an OpenStreetMap with different types of marker as two or more markers can have same text on their markers and there are a lot of markers like those with different text and the whole work will be done when the body loads.
Can anyone give me appropriate suggestion?
Thanks
Khandaker Mustakimur Rahman

Comment: Your wording is very unclear and I can't understand what your question is. I think you'll get more answers if you rewrite this to use correct grammar and add more details.

Comment: I changed the details, hope you will now understand what I require?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is how to draw a series of markers with popup balloon text over a map that uses OpenStreetMap data, and display that annotated map in a web page. If that's the case, you'll need to

1. Find a map server that can serve the OpenStreetMap tiles, or make your own.
2. Use a JavaScript map-drawing library in your page to load tiles from the server, draw them on the page, and the place markers and popups on the map.

Two easy options I know of for map servers are the ones hosted by [CloudMade](http://www.cloudmade.com), which you'll need to sign up for a free developer key to access, and the ones hosted by [MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map), which you can access freely without an API key.

There are several JavaScript libraries that you can use to draw maps in a "widget" on your webpage, but the most common are [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org) and [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com). Each of these libraries has a basic tutorial showing how to use it to draw a map on a page, though Leaflet's is nicer and friendlier. Once you decide on which library to use, you can look through its documentation to find out how to draw markers with text in popup balloons, or come back to StackOverflow to ask a more specific question.

For a good overview of the technologies involved in drawing an OpenStreetMap map on your web page, check out [switch2osm.org](http://www.switch2osm.org).